# I am using spring boot and mysql. I can't send post request as raw json

Tags: spring-data-jpa, postman

### [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVzvd.png)

### [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvAZN.png)

### [I send it with a parameter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGFOE.png)

When I enter the data in json format, it returns null. When I give it a parameter, it works fine. I need to send it in json format for use in react axios.

Comment: You have to handle JSON properly, add `@RequestBody` annonation to the method parameter that should receive `JSON` data.

Comment: You are welcome, now please update your post by putting the codes as the plain text format for better readability. And also post your solution as the answer, which can be helpful for others with the same issue